# how to give license in installshield 2013

Tags: licensing, installshield

i have ism file which is generated by installshield 2008.
i built exe file from iscmdbld.exe command using trial version of installshield 2013 , now i want to build msi from iscmdbld.exe command using  license version of installshield 2013 , so how  will this work ? am i required to install installshield 2013 on every system where i want to build msi file from ism file OR only install on 1 system and save ism file(generated by installshield 2008) into installshield 2013 and with this ism i build msi file from any system where installshield is not required .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Standalone Build module, InstallShield Premier edition provides 5 Standalone Build modules.